# Normalize vs Transform

Tags: generalized-linear-model, normalization, biostatistics

I am working will pollination data and have quite a few variables and few of them are not normally distributed. I tried transforming them yet few again are not normal. In that case I was suggested to "normalise" my data and not transform as I have variables as small as the number of fruit set to as big as landscape ones. Kindly suggest the right way of doing it. I am just starting to learn R. I am planning to do GLM (Generalized Linear Model) with this set of data

Comment: Please show what you have  done so far and where exactly did you get stuck, it will make it easier for people to suggest concrete solutions. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Are you saying you want to transform data which is not normally distributed (e.g. it has a Rayleigh distribution) into a normal distribution? That would be wrong.

Comment: @plamut I checked for normality using shapiro.test() in R n found some of my variables were not normally distributed. Hence I tried to transform them (arcsin - proportion,log-continuous and sqroot to count data). Some variables showed normal distribution after transformation while some normally distributed data showed reverse trend. 1. is it necessary to check for normality? 2. necessary to transform? or advisable to normalize as I have landscape variables which are in hectares and fruit:flower rations.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I checked for normality using shapiro.test() in R n found some of my variables were not normally distributed. Hence I tried to transform them (arcsin - proportion,log-continuous and sqroot to count data). Some variables showed normal distribution after transformation while some normally distributed data showed reverse trend. 1. is it necessary to check for normality? 2. necessary to transform? or advisable to normalize as I have landscape variables which are in hectares and fruit:flower ratio

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "variables as small as [...] to as big as [...]". I'm not sure what notion of size you are considering.